# SQL Server 2008 with recompile

Tags: sql-server, recompile, sql-execution-plan

My client wants *with recompile* in every stored procedure as a quick fix for parameter sniffing. I advised against this, but nonetheless they want to give it a shot.

Now, the database exists of hundreds and hundreds stored procedures. 
**My question**: Can I alter a instance level setting instead of changing every stored proc (whether using macro's or not, to make my life easier)?

I repeat: yes I know I shouldn't do this. But hopefully the performance will drop further and I can make my point.

**Edit:** I can see some votes to close this question. However, I think it's a fair question to ask. I already stated this is not a smart move, but answers like 'trace flag 4136' are very constructive.

Comment: It's such a bad plan that I doubt they'd spend time implementing a feature to let you do this.

Comment: If the goal is a "quick fix for parameter sniffing" have you looked at [trace flag 4136](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/980653)?

Comment: One of the close votes is mine, and it was a vote to move it to [dba](http://dba.stackexchange.com/), not an outright "this isn't a valid question", more of a "DBAs are more likely to be able to answer this than programmers, per se"